# Using JQuery to clone a "select" - selecting an option from the drop down does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is HTML/JQuery code sample. 
I would like to clone a "select".
The "select" is indeed cloned (BTW, twice for some reason, which is another question) but when using the mouse to select an item from the list of options, the item is not selected and not updated in the UI.

Would be great to get some tips on this.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="" method="POST" id="id_of_form">
            <div id="id_div_selection_options">
                <select id="id_selection_options">
                    <option value="a">a</option>
                    <option value="b">b</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <p>
        <a id="add" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Add another item</a>
    </p>
</body>


{% block extra-js %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function addEntry(btn) {
            var cloned = $('#id_div_selection_options').clone();
            cloned.attr('id', 'id_of_dup');
            cloned.appendTo($("#id_of_form"));
        }

        // Register the click event handlers
        $("#add").click(function() {
            return addEntry(this);
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock extra-js %}
```

TX
Guy

Comment: seems to be fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Q48LF/1/ any error in the console

Comment: A jsFiddle link would be helpful.

Comment: You're cloning a `div` and changing `id` of it, but not changing `id` of the cloned `select`.

Comment: @Arun P Johny: Console: no message after I click the button. On page load there is: Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type image/x-png: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/images/icons-18-white.png"

Comment: @Teemu: change the id using the "Element view" - same issue

Comment: @trunks175: Arun P Johny just did

Comment: Its a JQuery bug.

Here is the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950234/why-a-select-in-a-cloned-div-has-a-wrong-behavior-when-refreshed

Answer (score 0):

you need `name` attribute of select to post the value..

```
 <select id="id_selection_options" name="someName[]">
                               //--^^^ here---
```

using array in name to post multiple values

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but still the same problem: <select id="id_selection_options" name="my_select_name">

Comment: Any other suggestions?